# CastError in mongoDB nearSphere method in mongoose 3.8.3

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geospatial, geo

I use in mongoose version 3.8.3 the mongoDB $nearSphere method to find nearby locations.

```
mongoose.models['Event']
        .find({ loc : 
                { 
                    $nearSphere : 
                    { 
                        $geometry : loc,
                        $maxDistance : 100000
                    }
                }           
         })
        .limit(100)
        .exec(function (err, events)
        {
            console.log(err)
            ...
        }
```

The loc field in the Events Scheme has a '2dsphere' index:

```
var EventSchema = new Schema
({  
    ...
    loc: 
    {
        type: { type: String },
        coordinates: { type: [Number], index: '2dsphere' }
    },
    ...
});
```

The variable loc is of type 'Point'. An example is:

```
{ coordinates: [ 12.93598683338508, 48.43299197266921 ], type: 'Point' }
```

After executing the above search statement I always get the error:

```
2013-12-27T08:46:57.997102+00:00 app[web.1]: { message: 'Cast to number failed for value "Point" at path "__QueryCasting__"',
2013-12-27T08:46:57.997105+00:00 app[web.1]:   name: 'CastError',
2013-12-27T08:46:57.997107+00:00 app[web.1]:   type: 'number',
2013-12-27T08:46:57.997108+00:00 app[web.1]:   value: 'Point',
2013-12-27T08:46:57.997110+00:00 app[web.1]:   path: '__QueryCasting__' }
```

Can somebody figure out why this error appears and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in Mongoose. I have filed an issue:
https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/1874

I've got two workarounds to suggest.

I patched mongoose/lib/query.js by changing:

```
} else if (('$near' == geo || '$geoIntersects' == geo) &&
```

to

```
} else if (('$near' == geo || '$nearSphere' == geo || '$geoIntersects' == geo) &&
```

And it worked for me (mongoose 3.8.3).

Secondly, you could run the query as a "legacy" coordinate pair (you'd need to convert the maxDistance to radians).
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nearSphere/

Comment: So I have the same issue, whats going on here. Mongoose is now 3.8.8 has this issue being fixed? Im still having it. I actually run the command in MongoDB shell and works just fine.. it is Mongoose that is not working

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose has a built-in method for this called [`near()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-near), which accepts a GeoJSON Point for spherical geospatial queries.

From the docs:

> Specifies a $near or $nearSphere condition

So, instead of:

```
mongoose.models['Event']
    .find({ loc : 
            { 
                $nearSphere : 
                { 
                    $geometry : loc,
                    $maxDistance : 100000
                }
            }           
     }).limit(100).exec(function (err, events) { ... });
```

Try this:

```
mongoose.models['Event']
    .near('loc', {
        center: loc,
        maxDistance : 100000
    }).limit(100).exec(function (err, events) { ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a bug in mongoose, you should be doing find() on 'loc.coordinates', not just 'loc', because that's the field that the 2dsphere index is on. Right now, even if mongoose casts this query without failing, the mongodb server will return an error because you're trying to run $nearSphere on a field without a geo index. FWIW the 1 liner fix will be in the next minor release of mongoose, but you should also change your query code.